# One canvas, two dom elements?

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, element

Is it possible to have two dom elements reference the same canvas, so that one canvas is shown in two places without requiring a second canvas?

Comment: Take a look a cloning the canvas: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/html5-canvas/9781449308032/ch04s09.html

Answer (score 1):

**Sure!**

Use the html5 canvas data url as a background for multiple elements:

```
$('.bk').css('background-image','url('+canvas.toDataURL()+')');
```

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
ctx.strokeStyle='gray';
ctx.lineWidth=3;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50,50,40,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

$('.bk').css('background-image','url('+canvas.toDataURL()+')');
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
.bk{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Canvas</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
<h4>Two Divs containing the same canvas background</h4>
<div class=bk>One</div>
<div class=bk>Two</div>
```

Comment: Works for static canvases, but for animated ones... I think 2 elements and a simple `drawImage(sourceCanvas,x,y)` is a way better option

Comment: @Kaiido. Animation...Where do you see animation in the question? 8-) But if you need a few animating objects you can use CSS positioning. But, yes `firstCanvasContext.drawImage(SecondCanvas...)` works but multiple canvases are prohibited by the questioner. :-)

Comment: I don't see anything in OP but I'm almost sure someone will come here and try it with animated canvas. Also, I don't see why this prohibition in OP

Comment: @Kaiido. Sure ... I just answered the question as given ... but I'm sure other questions will involve animation and staging canvases.